# Bloquear acesso de navegadores sem suporte ao html5

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Já pesquisei e encontrei algumas formas de "barrar" o acesso de navegadores específicos, mas teria alguma forma de fazer isso com todos que não possuírem suporte ao html5?

Comment: Bom você pode utilizar [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

Comment: Barrar qualquer tipo de browser só por ser antigo com certeza não é uma boa prática... O ideal é tratar seu conteúdo para os navegadores antigo seja com "polyfill for old browsers" ou com o CSS

Comment: Acho interessante barrar. Uma forma talvez seja restringindo a conexão para TLS 1.2. Isso não tem haver com HTML5, de fato. Mas, navegadores antigos não conseguirão fazer o handshake, assim somente os navegadores modernos terão suporte, a probabilidade dele ter suporte ao HTML5 é extremamente alta. Também fico no aguardo de uma solução mais eficiente, se houver.

Comment: Minha aplicação web está ficando meio complexa e estou tentando minimiza-la ao máximo, se isso realmente for possível conseguirei reduzir muita coisa, acho válido pois não vejo motivo de utilizar navegadores antigos sem suporte ao html5 como padrão, pelo que vi teria que fazer algum tipo de gambiarra com o modernizr porém pelo que pesquisei não funcionária em todos os casos...

Comment: Bloquear o acesso talvez seja radical demais... Que tal mostrar um aviso ao usuário para que ele realize o update do navegador?
 http://outdatedbrowser.com/en/project